Numerous validation errors using HasQueryFilter()
I'm trying to implement soft delete using the techniques describes in this video and this article.
I added two columns to my entity.
public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
public DateTime? DeletedOnUtc { get; set; }

And I added the following to my OnModelCreating.
builder.Entity<Company>().HasQueryFilter(c => c.IsDeleted == false);

builder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasIndex(c => c.IsDeleted)
    .HasFilter("IsDeleted = 0");

But when I add a migration using these changes, I get numerous validation warnings concerning related tables.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'CompanyReport'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Customer'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Image'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'PdfTemplate'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Product'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'ProductCategory'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'ReportJob'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'CompanyReport'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'CompanyReport'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Customer'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Customer'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Image'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Image'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'PdfTemplate'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'PdfTemplate'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Product'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'Product'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10622]
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'ProductCategory'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'ProductCategory'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'ReportJob'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.
Entity 'Company' has a global query filter defined and is the required end of a relationship with the entity 'ReportJob'. This may lead to unexpected results when the required entity is filtered out. Either configure the navigation as optional, or define matching query filters for both entities in the navigation. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131316 for more information.

I read the link, but it isn't clear why I need to deal with this while the articles I mentioned don't. Do I really need to modify every one of my existing foreign keys?
Does someone who understands this better explain what I'm doing wrong?

The issue is that you have the IsDeleted query filter on Company but unlike a hard-delete with the option of doing a cascade delete vs. set FK to null, any entity that holds a FK reference to company needs to be able to deal with the fact that it's referenced Company could be marked as deleted.
For instance if we have a Company and an Order, where Order contains a non-null-able CompanyId and-or marked as Required, EF is warning you that with the QueryFilter, a company that "IsDeleted = True" won't be returned so Orders that reference that company may be excluded, or the company included when queried.
When the company is marked as deleted there is nothing ensuring the Order.IsDeleted will also be set to True for all orders for that company. The suggestion from EF is that Order.Company should be marked as Null-able and not Required to ensure Orders that aren't marked as deleted, but their Company is marked as Deleted, can still be returned.
Query filters can be a bit of a double-edged blade in that a deleted Company could still be a valid, readable record when in the context of related data. Marking a company as deleted makes sense that the company no longer sources orders, but does not necessarily invalidate past orders. So if I mark a company as Deleted, I may not be able to associate it to future orders, but it still makes sense to bring it up in the context of historical orders. A Query Filter can have issue with this, requiring us to remember to disable the query filter on Company in order to get the related data.
Personally I don't use query filters for soft-delete, instead have it applied as part of a base rule in a Repository pattern. By default when querying entities at the top level I enforce the IsDeleted filter, but related entities will always be across all entities. I.e. default to only active orders, but for all active orders the Customers/Companies related data can include inactive relations.
Edit: So for instance if we have Orders /w
public class Order 
{
    // ...

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

... where Company has an IsDeleted soft-delete flag. EF will give us a validation warning that Company is required but is referencing an entity with a query filter which may prevent records from coming back. If I have 4 Orders, 2 against Company ID #1, and 2 against Company ID #2 and I mark Company #2 as IsDeleted then the following two queries will return different data:
var orders1 = context.Orders.ToList();
var orders2 = context.Orders.Include(x => x.Company).ToList();

orders1 will contain the 4 orders, while orders2 will only return the two orders for Company #1 as Company #2 is filtered out. The two orders for CompanyId #2 in orders1 will be returned and have their CompanyId of 2 if the FK is exposed. What is interesting is that if the DbContext happens to be tracking the soft-deleted company #2 then orders1 will have the deleted Company populated.
context.Companies.IgnoreQueryFilters().ToList(); // simply load and track all companies including deleted ones.
var orders1 = context.Orders.ToList();
var orders2 = context.Orders.Include(x => x.Company).ToList();

Here even though we do not eager load the companies in orders1, it will have all orders and the references to Company #1 and #2 will be present and intact. orders2 will still only contain the orders for company #1.
If we change the Order configuration to:
public class Order 
{
    // ...

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company? Company { get; set; }
}

then running the following queries:
var orders1 = context.Orders.ToList();
var orders2 = context.Orders.Include(x => x.Company).ToList();

... will both return all of the orders in both cases. For the orders belonging to Company #2, the CompanyId will be populated, but the Company reference will be left as #null. If CompanyId is exposed in the entity it still needs to be marked as null-able (int?) if left as int then EF treats it as required resulting in the excluded behaviour.

Thanks. So, in the scenario you described, would a query on Orders set null the company/company ID to null? That's the part I'm having trouble envisioning. And yes, like you, I'm questioning if this is the approach I want to take.

Whether they are null-able or not if the company is marked as IsDeleted then querying entities that reference a required Company will not return data even though those related records have a FK set, rather than simply returning the data with null Company references if you include the Company. I have expanded the answer to demonstrate the behaviour. At the end of the day it is a validation warning that you might get unexpected results, not a model error.
